# regular expression to get nth value in comma separated values

Tags: java, regex

This query

```
/(?:[^\,]*\,){10}([^,]*)/
```

returns all the values till 10th value, but I am looking for a query that only gives me 10th value. Can someone help?

Comment: What language are you using, and can you offer a description of what you are trying to do here?

Comment: I want a java regex
I have logs like that has many rows like this : "20266547:20000256","-","20000256","20266547","-",9349,"-","-","2016-01-23","04:41:39","GET /dojo/1.10.4-std/dojo/fx.js HTTP/1.1",200,"3433","SCRUB_1_URL"
I want to get 10th value from each row

Comment: Yes but what language are you using?  Your second capture group already is capturing the 10th value, so all you need to do is to extract it.

Comment: My query gives a long string containing every value till 10th . not the 10th value

Comment: Last time I will ask you: what language are you using?

Comment: Can you post the Java code you are currently using?

Comment: I am using java regex on logentries.com I dont have to use java code there. it is a log managing website and allows searching using regexps

Comment: you shouldn't use regexp to parse a csv file: you have sometime to handle quotes or multiline, and regexp didn't fit well for this kind of task

Comment: java doesn't use slashes to delimit regex, but your posted regex has wrapping slashes. are you sure you're using java and not javascript (which does use slashes)?

Answer (score 2):

Although you can parse CSV's with regex, or with String#split, why reinvent the wheel?  There are nice [CSV libraries](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) you can use, and they will handle a lot special cases for you.  For instance, your solution doesn't handle quoted strings with commas.  Maybe you don't need that yet, but you might as well guard against it needing it in the future.  Here's how you would do it:

```
 File csvData = new File("/path/to/csv");
 CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(csvData, CSVFormat.RFC4180);
 for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parser) {
     String item10 = csvRecord.get(9) 
 }
```

Comment: I need a solution only for logentries.com. Then I can use their API with regexp filter to get filtered logs

Answer (score 1):

```
public String get10thElement(String input) {
    // String input = "\"20266547:20000256\",\"-\",\"20000256\",\"20266547\",\"-\",9349,\"-\",\"-\",\"2016-01-23\",\"04:‌​41:39\",\"GET /dojo/1.10.4-std/dojo/fx.js HTTP/1.1\",200,\"3433\",\"SCRUB_1_URL\"";
    String[] elements = input.split(",");
    return elements[9];
}
```

You've tagged this as Java. Use the split method.

Answer (score 0):

From the Logentries.com [documentation](https://logentries.com/doc/regex/#regex-field-extreaction), I think you want something along these lines:

```
where(/(?:[^\,]*\,){10}(?P<tenthItem>([^,]*))/)
```

This will direct the tenth matching item into a variable called `tenthItem`.  Note carefully the syntax being used here:

```
(?P<tenthItem>([^,]*))
```

This says that you want whatever matches `([^,]*)` to go into a variable named `tenthItem`.

Comment: This doesn't work if there is a comma between quotes

Comment: @JérémieB I think his question is mainly focused on how to get regex working for him using Logentries.  As to whether his original regex will work in all cases, this is another story.